# ObjectBox: db browser not working

Tags: android, objectbox

I did a project with all dependencies and initialization but db browser does not start. I don't understand where I made a mistake.
[Sample project](https://github.com/kenji47/BubbleNotes)

project build.gradle

```
    allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectbox"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

dependencies {
    debugCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:$objectbox"
    releaseCompile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectbox"
}
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

Application class

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(App.this).build();

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            new AndroidObjectBrowser(boxStore).start(this);
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }
        context = this;
    }
```

Comment: have you been watching logcat for any warnings/errors? Did you try the example? https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/tree/master/objectbox-example

Comment: There's no errors in logcat. The example app working fine

Comment: I don't spot anything obvious. Please double check that you are building the debug build variant. Also what's the result of "BoxStore.isObjectBrowserAvailable()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in internet permission in manifest. After adding this line, the browser started working.

```
<!-- For Object Browser -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```